# Reference request: Wigner-D matrix and Type-L vectors

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

I am trying to understand [this paper](https://openreview.net/forum?id=KwmPfARgOTD). There is a part (on page 3 of the said paper) where the authors discuss irreducible representations. There, the authors mentioned Wigner-$D$ matrices and Type-$L$ vectors.

I am very new to group representation theory and am currently reading [these lecture notes](https://tartarus.org/gareth/maths/notes/ii/Representation_Theory.pdf) to understand the basics. However, no matter where I look, I cannot find mentions of Wigner-$D$ matrics or Type-$L$ vectors.

Is there some source for this?